# iOS 15 Untrusted Developer issue

Tags: xcode, apple-developer, ios15

I have updated recently to a new iOS 15 and after I built and run my application in Xcode, while have been logged in with a same developer account as before iOS 15 installation, I get this message:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch com.xyz.xyz.xyz
> because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or
> its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.

and the error log:

> ### Could not launch “my-project0name” Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
> Code: 3 Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to
> launch com.xyz.xyz.xyz because it has an invalid code signature,
> inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted
> by the user. User Info: {
> DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
> IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
> RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. Unable to launch com.xyz.xyz.xyz because it has an invalid
> code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been
> explicitly trusted by the user."; }

System Information

> macOS Version 11.6 (Build 20G165) Xcode 13.0 (19234) (Build 13A233)
> Timestamp: 2021-09-21T12:36:18+02:00

Earlier (on iOS14), this could be solved by going to:

```
Settings.app -> General -> Profile -> Select Profile -> Trust
```

But now (on iOS15) I can't actually find it at that location. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [@ujell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1311234/ujell) pointed out. The provisioning profile generated prior **iOS 15** is preventing installation on the new release. Therefore, you will need to generate a new provisioning profile for your app. Try the following:

- Quit Xcode
- Go to the directory of cached provisioning profiles (cd
  ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/)
- Back up the existing
  files to another directory
- Remove all profiles listed under
  ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
- Launch Xcode
- Install/run the app on your device

Xcode will detect that there are no eligible profiles on your local system and request a new one during the next build to a device. The new profile will be compliance with iOS 15 provisioning.

NOTE: if it still doesn't work, then install the [iOS 15.2 beta release](https://developer.apple.com/download/#ios-restore-images-iphone-new) (Build 19C5026i or later) on your device and try the steps above again.

Comment: WOW! Thank you!  Deleting all the profiles in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ did work! now using Monterey - Xcode 13 and my iPhone 7 with iOS 15.1 !

Comment: It worked for me on Big Sur on iOS 15.1.

Comment: Didn't work. Disabled automatic signing, closed Xcode, deleted provisionings, restarted Xcode, reenabled automatic signing (did retrieve new signing). The app runs on device with internet access but not on device on WIFI without internet access. App doesent show up in device management so can't verify it manually.

Comment: Disabling automatic signing and creating a prov. profile manually didn't help either.
Really problematic that you can't develop iOS apps for offline devices anymore.

Comment: It did't worked for me on Venture on iOS 16.1.

Answer (score 23):

iOS 15 changed trusted application position to:

*Settings -> General ->  VPN & Device Management*

Then you can see your application under the `Developer App`, click it and verify it.

Comment: I think this is not so correct. For example on 15.3.1, there is no “Trust” option in that menu

Comment: well, `trust it` is not a buttom, you just need to click , then there will some hint named trust it or verify it

Comment: There is nothing showing up in that menu except vpn button and “Sign in to work on a school account” button…

Comment: Works on ios 16.2.

Comment: I think this is not correct. I using Xcode 15 and iOS17, there is no option in that menu.

Answer (score 19):

From what i understand, this might be a bug connected to iOS 15 / xcode 13.

I found a solution which is to create a new Apple ID and use it to sign your app in xcode.

You can add a new team by going into "Signing & Capabilities"-tab and select "Add account" where you select a team.

Once you've done this and run the application on your device again, the option to trust the application in Settings > General > Device Management should appear!

Comment: Ok but will I be able to run my application using my old account (my old team) ? Cause this is not a solution for me. My goal is to continue using my old apple ID…

Comment: This is sooooo frustrating!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I was exchanging emails with apple developers support and they always sent me to the dev forums. And there a bunch of people have the same problem… I'm so upset with this!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Any update on this from Apple?

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, it looks like, the problem occurs only with IOS >hardware< real devices running >= iOS 15

I see no option in Settings allowing me to set the app dev  as trusted.

This does NOT occur with my older (real) iPad Air, running with iOS 12.5. The app runs immediately without prompting for trust etc.

It also runs without problems on Xcode's simulator devices with iOS 15.
So yes, I think it is an iOS 15 and/or Xcode issue.
reported this to Apple.

Comment: Are you using Xcode managed profile? What worked for me was disabling the automatic signing and closing Xcode, removing all provisioning profiles from "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles" folder and-reenabling the automatic signing back. Though I assume removing only the profile for the specific app would also work, in my case I had no reason to be picky and about to nuke everything related with Xcode in my system anyway to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

iOS 13
in your iphone,got to
**Settings -> General -> VPN and device management -> Developer app** ->Trust and accept

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue happened for me:

> failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.OgSDGs/extracted/Payload/APP_NAME : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)

and as pointed out by some folks on [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737156) on Apple's forum, simply deleting the app and then installing it solved the issue. Hope it saves some people who dig into the comments here some time, it sure cost me half an hour of my day..

Answer (score 1):

At least my issue was the result of Apple again messing with the code signing creating a ling tail of side effects.
iOS15 code signs differentially on the "new" type of certificates.

I'm developing an app that is connection to a device via WIFI without internet connection.
The initial development was done on Xcode 13.1 and an iOS14 iPad. That worked well. As usual the iPad needed to be on a WIFI with internet connection at the first launch to verify the code signing. After that it was fine to launch the app from Xcode to the iPad while it being on the WIFI without internet connection. The app didn't need any additional code signing verification.

After updating the iPad to iOS15 every launch started to fail with the error unverified when the iPad was on WIFI without internet connection. Launching on the iPAD on WIFI with internet connection was fine.
It seems like iOS15 causes apps to verify code signing on every launch - not only the first any more.

After searching and fiddling with Provisioning Profiles for several days I found out that Apple now has two different types of certificates - an "iOS Development" certificate and a "Apple development" certificate. The latter being the "new" thing.
Deleting my automatically created certificate and creating a "new" - and then a new provisioning profile solved my problems.
My app now only needs to verify code signing at the first launch.

This fixed my code signing / developer verification issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

iOS 15:

Settings -> General -> VPN and device manage -> business apps -> Tap on your certificate and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but to anyone still searching for a solution to this problem, I finally fixed it by turning on automatic date & time settings.

On your iPhone: go to **Settings**  > **General** > **Date & Time.**
Then turn off and on again the "**Set Automatically**" setting.

For somme absurd and unknown reason that seemed to solve the problem, for me at least.
Hope it helps.

Note: I have an iPhone 7 with iOS 15.6 and i use xCode 13.4.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Just install the Developer app on the physical host iOS device.
2. Go to account and signin from you developer apple id
3. Now under Settings > General > VPN & Device Management you'll be able to see organisations.
4. Trust the ones you want to
5. You'll now be able to open the applications signed by that organisation

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting certificates as @Al Bencomo suggested - didn't help.
Restarted phone - didn't help.
I tried manually adding certificate from AppStore connect, adding it to XCode and reinstall app again - didn't help.

Then, I just clicked "turn On" VPN in Device Management and was able to lunch my app...

So either step 1, 2 or 3 need more time or VPN somehow helped...

Answer (score 0):

The only option that worked for me was to clear trusted computers on the iPhone and then pair it again.

Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted Computers