# xcode build to iPhone device it has an invalid code signature

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanted to build my project in my iPhone, I got this error message

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. 
Unable to launch com.xxxx.test because it has an invalid code signature, 
inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.
```

I tried to go to `settings> general> VPN and device management` but I have nothing inside it I only have the possibility to log in with a work or school account and nothing else. My app does not appear in the VPN and device management section therefore I cannot authorize anything.How can I fix it? Thanks.

Xcode 13.0
iPhone X iOS 15

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69267550/ios-15-untrusted-developer-issue. I have a feeling we're going to be seeing a lot of these.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is same but the error message looks like we can't find the trust setting.

Answer (score 10):

This solved my case.

```
iPhone Settings -> General -> VPN and device management -> From "Developer App" section found "Apple Development: APPLE_ID" -> Trust
```

See the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow. My eyes have been skipping the VPN start... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have Internet connection on your device. My connection was off - it was the reason why Apple couldn't check my developer's profile.

Comment: my phone's network is ok

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions :

- Solution 1: open System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Add a user account (build with the new user is successfully
- Solution 2: Open Keychain Access -> choose System, All Items -> delete certificate Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority